# React Native - ScrollView/ListView lose their scroll positions after pushing a new scene

Tags: react-native, react-native-listview

Essentially I just need this for my ListView, but ScrollView would probably be useful too. So when I scroll down a page in a ListView, click an item pushing to a new scene, and then pop back I want to remember where I was, else the user has to scroll all the way back to their previous position again which could be pretty frustrating.

Any help would be grateful.

Comment: can you provide more details to your routing etc.? maybe a little example to get a hint how you're trying to do this? here is a guide how to correctly ask questions https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask ;-)

Comment: I'm using this library for routing between scenes - https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux - So upon clicking a row in my ListView I'd invoke the function `Actions.anotherPage({customProp: 123})` and then on that page when the user clicks the back button in the navigation bar on iOS it would `Route.pop()` back to return to the original scene.

Comment: as I don't have an example of your code I have to start guessing. I had this issue once with this library when my scenes weren't set up correctly and on a click on a new route the old route was unmounted. Make sure your routes (or shemas) are setted on the same level and nested on the same area. Per default your ListView or ScrollView should stay scrolled when you open a new route

Comment: Sorry, here is a cutdown example of my scenes on my index.ios.js - https://pastebin.com/Q9xYtrcn - I hadn't realised but it's all my scenes which don't scroll to their previous position. Initially I had only noticed it on one ListView. I tried `componentWillUnmount` and put a console.log in there but that doesn't print out so it doesn't seem to be unmounting my scene after a push.

Comment: thank you for your example (I think you are missing a `</Scene>` at the end of your construct ;-)). But this shouldn't be the issue. Maybe your redux state sets a new Router/Scene/Stack on every new tab/route. A good help for this is the famous redux-logger https://github.com/evgenyrodionov/redux-logger with this tool you can detect a wrong state very fast

Comment: That may just be my bad copying/pasting. Thanks I'm trying the logger - seems really useful! Everything seems normal on the router actions called `REACT_NATIVE_ROUTER_FLUX_PUSH` then `REACT_NATIVE_ROUTER_FLUX_FOCUS`. I've gone back through the router setup docs but that seems similar to my approach too.

Comment: Figured it out... I was rendering null on my scenes while loading data from my API. As soon as I removed this it works and remembers my previous scroll position. Thanks for your help!